Simple form association, custom class based on object
In my view I have this line to display a list of radio_button for the category association
<%= f.association :category, collection: @available_categories, as: :radio_buttons, input_html: { class: ''} %>

How could I have custom class base on a category field. For exemple having class: 'project' if the category attribute is_project is true
I have try something like that
<%= f.association :category, collection: @available_categories, as: :radio_buttons, input_html: { class: (:is_project ? 'project' : '')} %>

Any help will be appreciated

you can use dom_class to convert any record to a generic class name.
What object do you want to check if it's a project or not? the object associated to the form, or each category of @available_categories ?

@wacko each category of @available_categories in fact if the category attribute is_project is true I want the radio_button  to have class 'project'

The method takes an optional block which yields the builder for the actual inputs. The SimpleForm readme doesn't have a good example but it works kind of like the lower level Rails collection_checkboxes helper that SimpleForm wraps. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes

Something like f.association :category, collection: @available_categories, as: :radio_buttons, { |b|  b.label { b.input(class: b.some_predicate_method) + b.text } ) }.
